# fetch data in nuxt3 not rendering in templete

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am trying to set api in nuxt 3 using this code:

```
<template>

    <div>
        <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="planet in planets" :key="planet.slug">
                <NuxtLink :to="planet.slug">
                    {{ planet.title }}
                </NuxtLink>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    async fetch() {
        this.planets = await fetch('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/planets').then(res => 
        res.json()

        )
    },
    data() {
        return {
            planets: [],
        } 
    },
}
</script>
```

but I only got this result in browser!!

"planets": []

I trid to use usefetch and useAsyncData but couldnot success
could anyone help me to know my mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to perform data fetching using the Option API : https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching#options-api-support

So in your case, this is how you should fetch your data.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ $data }}</pre>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="planet in planets" :key="planet.slug">
        <NuxtLink :to="planet.slug">
          {{ planet.title }}
        </NuxtLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default defineNuxtComponent({
  fetchKey: 'hello',
  async asyncData() {
    return {
      planets: await $fetch('https://api.nuxtjs.dev/planets'),
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

Please, note that, as the doc says, using `<script setup lang="ts">` is the recommended way of declaring Vue components in Nuxt 3.

You can find more information about it here: https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/define-nuxt-component

Comment: thank you BghinC, one more question if you don't mind: shall I make some change if I want to render data from the local server? because when i replace api to the local path('/api/users') no data Showen!